# Angular edit a copy of a copy

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having a few problems editing a copy of a copy.

When you first edit a record it is assigned to a `$scope.original` and a copy is taken for editing and stored in `$scope.copy` which can be changed and saved back to `$scope.original` which in-turn updates `$scope.something` correctly.

The problem is while editing the first record if you then take a copy of one of the values for further editing, it doesn't get updated when the `$scope.saveSomething()` function is called.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.Something = [{
    name: "Aye",
    desc: new Date()
  }, {
    name: "Bee",
    desc: new Date()
  }, {
    name: "See",
    desc: new Date()
  }];

  //=================== First copy

  $scope.edit = function(what) {
    $scope.original = what;
    $scope.copy = angular.copy(what);
  }

  $scope.save = function(copy) {
    angular.copy($scope.copy, $scope.original);
    $scope.cancel();
  }

  $scope.cancel = function() {
    $scope.copy = null;
  }

  //=================== Second copy

  $scope.editName = function(what) {
    $scope.originalName = what;
    $scope.copyName = angular.copy(what);
  }

  $scope.saveName = function() {
    angular.copy($scope.copyName, $scope.originalName);
    $scope.cancelName();
  }

  $scope.cancelName = function() {
    $scope.copyName = null;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="s in Something">
      <pre>{{s | json}}</pre>
      <a ng-click='edit(s)'>edit</a>
      <br/>
      <br/>
    </div>

    <input type='text' ng-model='copy.name' />
    <input type='text' ng-model='copy.desc' />
    <br/>
    <button ng-click='save(copy)' ng-disabled="!copy">save</button>
    <button ng-click='cancel()' ng-disabled="!copy">cancel</button>
    <a ng-click='editName(copy.name)'>edit name</a>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type='text' ng-model='copyName' />
    <br>
    <button ng-click='saveName()' ng-disabled="!originalName">saveName</button>
    <button ng-click='cancelName()' ng-disabled="!originalName">cancelName</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm fairly new to Angular, and have been scratching my head on this one for a while now, any ideas why?

## Edit

Updated the code to give a better example, the first version suggested that you might know which value of the first edit's values you were editing, and the solution scarlz posted ( http://jsfiddle.net/Karl33to/w23ppp9r/ ) just sets that value directly in the second save function, but I need to be able to do the second edit on any of the values that the first edit loads.

Have also created a fiddle if that's easier for you to run / fork http://jsfiddle.net/w23ppp9r/2/

Answer (score 1):

Your problem arises from your use of `angular.copy`. In `$scope.saveName`, your destination `$scope.originalName` is a string, which will result in angular throwing an error.

There is actually no reason to use `angular.copy` at all if you're working with primitives. Instead, you could use the following here:

```
$scope.editName = function(what) {
  $scope.originalName = what;
  $scope.copyName = what;
};

$scope.saveName = function() {
  $scope.copy.name = $scope.copyName;
  $scope.cancelName();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I made it clear in my first example that the second edit needs to be done without knowing which value you are editing (in the full app there are 10+ values that could be edited further in this way), I've now updated the code example to reflect this.

Comment: If there are 10+ values you could edit this way, then this is a typical use case for a directive, rather than a single controller.  A directive would allow you to use the solution arrived at above multiple times by leveraging an isolated scope.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to come up with a simple solution, which seems to work.

Instead of passing the primitive to the second edit function, if I pass in the key and a copy of the object instead, I can then update the first copy correctly.

Here's a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/w23ppp9r/3/
... and the relevant bit of code:

```
//=================== Second copy

$scope.editSomething = function(key, obj) {
    $scope.originalKey = key;
    $scope.originalObj = obj;
    $scope.copyVal = obj[key];
};

$scope.saveSomething = function(newVal) {
    $scope.originalObj[$scope.originalKey] = newVal;
    $scope.cancelEdit();
}

$scope.cancelEdit = function() {
    $scope.originalKey = null;
    $scope.originalObj = null;
    $scope.copyVal = null;
}
```

Is there a better answer?